# vmtools jdom dependency

Tags: xml, build

I am trying to run vmtools-0.5 [vmtools](http://www.vmsystems.net/vmtools/) on my machine.
What I can not figure out is what jdom version doe the vmtools require.

I have tried jdom 2, jdom 1.1.3 and jdom 1.1.2.
All of them have issues with compilation. The closest I got was with jdom 1.1.2.

However, I see these compilation errors when I try to run vmtools with jdom 1.1.2

```
C:\apps\dumps\vmtools-0.5\examples>javac -cp C:\apps\dumps\vmtools-0.5\vmtools-0.5.jar;C:\Users\ayusman\Desktop\jdom-1.1.2\build\jdom-1.1.2.jar XmlDiff.java
XmlDiff.java:107: cannot access org.jdom.input.DefaultJDOMFactory
class file for org.jdom.input.DefaultJDOMFactory not found
                        sb.setFactory(new DomFactory());
                                      ^
XmlDiff.java:123: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor XMLOutputter(java.lang.String,boolean)
location: class org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter
                        XMLOutputter xmlo = new XMLOutputter("  ", true);
                                            ^
XmlDiff.java:124: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setTextNormalize(boolean)
location: class org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter
                        xmlo.setTextNormalize(true);
                            ^
3 errors

C:\apps\dumps\vmtools-0.5\examples>
```

Has any body tried running vmtools; if so what is the exact jdom version they used?

Solution [[Adding for posterity:]]
I tried with the [jdom-b8](http://www.jdom.org/dist/binary/archive/jdom-b8.zip) version and it compiled fine.
In case somebody is looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, VMTools is built against JDom beta 7. There were likely been API changes between beta 7 and the 1.x version, and JDom 2 is significantly different.

Comment: yes, you are right. I should have updated this thread. I tried with jdom-b8 and it worked fine. Thanks for input.